# How to check if a given String is an English word in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, dictionary

I am looking for some library which take string as input and result boolean based on, if input string is present in english dictionary

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227839/quickest-easiest-way-to-acces-english-dictionary-in-a-java-scala-based-app

Answer (score 1):

For mac user default english dictionary can be found at location /usr/share/dict/web2

Hence we can,

```
>> var dict = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/usr/share/dict/web2").getLines.toSet

>> dict.contains("apple")
result : true

>> dict.contains("appl")
result : false
```

Comment: Does the Unix dict contain all possible word prefixes and suffixes?